# Cast to date failed for value "Invalid Date" (type Date)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose model I have made a model

```
const purchaseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    studentId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Student" },
    courseId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "course" },
    enrollmentDate: {
      type: Date,
    },
    expiryDate: {
      type: Date,
    },
    courseProgress: {
      type: Number,
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

I have deployed my code on render and trying to create a record using this model and the code for that is

```
let tod = new Date(Date.now());
let expDate = new Date(tod);
const today = tod.toISOString(); // Convert to ISODate string
expDate.setMonth(expDate.getMonth() + course.validity);
const expiryDate = expDate.toISOString();
// Create enrollment record
const purchase = await purchaseModel.create({
          studentId: student_id,
          courseId: course_id,
          enrollmentDate: today,
          expiryDate: expiryDate,
          progress: 0,
});
```

but it is giving me this error

```
Error: Purchase validation failed: expiryDate: Cast to date failed for value "Invalid Date" (type Date) at path "expiryDate"
    at ValidationError.inspect (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:50:26)
```

I have tested the same code on my local system it running fine but the deployed version is giving me this error.

Comment: Please check server time format and your local system time format.

Comment: on server it is " UTC " and on my local system it is "TZ". so how should I solve this conflict ? @KalpeshBoghara

Comment: The error is telling you that the variable `expiryDate` is  an `Invalid Date` so you should `console.log('expiryDate= ', expiryDate)` to see what it is. Also, what is `course.validity`? Could this be causing `expDate` to generate an invalid date. A number or string for `course.validity` will result in a different value.

Comment: `course.validity` is a number which I am adding in the months to set the expiry date of the purchase. @jQueeny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model requires a `Date`, however you run `.toISOString()` which returns a **string**, this does not work.

When you have to work with dates, then I recommend a 3rd part library, like [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [day.js](https://day.js.org/en/). Would be like this one:

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");
const purchase = await purchaseModel.create({
          studentId: student_id,
          courseId: course_id,
          enrollmentDate: DateTime.now().toJSDate(),
          expiryDate: DateTime.now().plus({ months: course.validity }).toJSDate(),
          progress: 0,
});
```